# Posting JSON to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am passing a JSON to my controller create method. I am trying to pass this JSON into my model/database. But I keep getting the error:

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

Am I not passing a hash?

JSON:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "name": "Tom",
      "sport": "Ski",
      "mood": "Happy",
      },
    {
      "name": "Robbie",
      "sport": "Swim",
      "mood": "sad",
      },
    {
      "name": "Ted",
      "sport": "Running",
      "mood": "Sleepy",
      },
  ]
}
```

Controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def create
    new_record = people_params
    records = People.new(new_record)
    records.save
  end

  private

  def people_params
    params.permit(people: [:name, :sport, :mood]).require(:people)
  end 
end
```

Schema:

```
  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "sport"
    t.string   "mood"
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ActiveRecord, the [`new`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-c-new) method doesn't take an array of hashes, just a single one. Whereas [`create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create) does allow an array of hashes, to create multiple models.

So you just need to change

```
new_record = people_params
records = People.new(new_record)
records.save
```

to

```
records = People.create(people_params)
```

If any are invalid, none will be saved, alternatively you can use [`create!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-create-21) to raise an error if any are invalid